How To Read Corrupted Record and Store it for later use in PySpark
I am using the below CSV File for fetching the corrupted records and storing it for later use:
id,name,age,salary,address,nominee
1,Manish,26,75000,bihar,nominee1
2,Nikita,23,100000,uttarpradesh,nominee2
3,Pritam,22,150000,Bangalore,India,nominee3
4,Prantosh,17,200000,Kolkata,India,nominee4
5,Vikash,31,300000,,nominee5

The Pyspark code used is as below :
emp_schema = StructType(
          [
              StructField("id",IntegerType(),True),
              StructField("name",StringType(),True),
              StructField("age",IntegerType(),True),
              StructField("salary",IntegerType(),True),
              StructField("address",StringType(),True),
              StructField("nominee",StringType(),True),
              StructField("_corrupt_record",StringType(),True),
          ]

)

df_after = spark.read.format("csv")\
            .option("header","true")\
            .schema(emp_schema)\
            .option("mode","PERMISSIVE")\
            .option("badrecords","/FileStore/tables/badrecords")\
            .load("/FileStore/tables/corrupt-2.csv")

On running the above code I should get the records with ID : 1,2 and 5 as output and a file created but in the ouput I am getting all the records as output and no file is created.
Output :
 id|   name|age|salary|     address|             nominee|     _corrupt_record|
+---+-------+---+------+------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|  1| Manish| 26| 75000|       bihar|            nominee1|                null|
|  2| Nikita| 23|100000|uttarpradesh|nominee2         ...|                null|
|  3| Pritam| 22|150000|   Bangalore|               India|3,Pritam,22,15000...|
|  4|Prantos| 17|200000|     Kolkata|               India|4,Prantos,17,2000...|
|  5| Vikash| 31|300000|        null|nominee5         ...|                null|
+---+-------+---+------+------------+--------------------+--------------------+


You won't get a separate dataframe. The rows with non-null values in _corrupt_record are bad records. You can filter them separately and write to a file.

I don't want a separate dataframe . I want the output in the dataframe to be noncorrupt record and the corrupt record in a separate file.

So filter the dataframes accordingly and then write them separately. What is stopping you?

@user_program are you using azure databricks
